# Typescript: How to make interface contain at least one type?

Tags: typescript

I have started working with `typescript`. I have a situation where I import available `types` from backend endpoints. A particular endpoint can support two type as param

Ex -

```
interface B extends A {
    value?: string,
    values?: string[]
}
```

Where `A` is the type imported from backend and it can have either `value: string` or `values: string[]`

For now I just made it optional for both which is not the great solution I believe. So how can I make the `interface B` either have `value` or `values`

Thanks

Comment: You can't. Interfaces describe what the class should look like. You can't describe if there should be at least one them. Write logic in the class which inherit the interface.

Comment: Of course you can, see [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHVhgBYDU4A2ArigN4BQyVAboSQFzIDOYUoA5gNzkC+55oSLEQoMWPHQhNkFKslrEpjFmxDsA2gF1ufcmACeAB1H5FAeSimS0gLxpMOKygA+98U6bd+CAPYgWyHCMqE4WHsh2pPKSjADkcLHIPNy+-mDIAEbBoZaStjLRikyM6rEAjLEANMixAExVNQDMsZpJ3EA).
Would be helpful to know how type `A` is defined.

Comment: I stand corrected. Interesting.

Comment: How about `{value: 'a', values: ['1','2',]}` - is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

The key to the "either or" type you're looking for is called a [union type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types). They are defined with the pipe `|` type operator. It basically means *"either this type OR that type"*.

For example:

```
type StringOrNumber = string | number;
```

Or:

```
type FooOrBar = { foo: string; } | { bar: string; };
```

Or, for your case:

```
interface IWithValue {
   value: string;
}

interface IWithValues {
   values: string[];
}

type IValueOrValues = IWithValue | IWithValues;
```

You can find an example in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=42&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHVhgBYDU4A2ArigN4BQyVAboSQFzIDOYUoA5gNzkC+55oSLEQoMWPHQhNkFKslrEpjFmxDsA2gF1ufcmACeAB1H5FAeSimS0gLxpMOKygA+98U6bd+CAPYgWyHCMqE4WHsh2pPKSjADkcLHIPNy+-mDIAEbBoZaStjLRikyM6rEAjLEANMixAExVNQDMsZpJ3EA).